# Android Studio 4.1 getString from resValue in build.gradle

Tags: android, android-studio-4.1

[image: build.gradle file]

[image: Error Code]

Hi all,

Before upgrade to Android Studio 4.1 there are just fine to get the string from resValue in build.gradle file.

After upgraded to Android Studio 4.1, then all the value to be called is showing error which like "strEnviornment.

But the weird thing is that can compile and run on the device which no problem at all.

But there the value still showing like error. Any idea to solve it in Android Studio 4.1?

Comment: That appears to be [a bug in Android Studio 4.1](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/171394797). It is unlikely that there is anything that you can do about it until the bug gets fixed.

Comment: Thx buddy. ya, u r correct. just have to wait the bug gets fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove following import line

`import android.R`